# What is the easiest label printer to program for (inexpensive printers)?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, label, thermal-printer

I know that Zebra is a pretty popular label standard out there, but what label printer has the easiest programming interface (SDK) for .NET 3.5 SP1?  I'm trying to focus on inexpensive thermal or thermal transfer label printers as well.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425617/what-options-are-available-to-developers-for-printing-to-a-dedicated-label-printe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zebra has an [easy to use SDK](http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/index/products/software/SDK.html) with a bunch of example code and a [GUI based label design application](http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/index/products/software/label_design_software/zebradesignerpro/zebradesigner.html) for creating the labels

Answer (score 0):

Choose a brand that makes its SDK easily available.  Download it, and judge yourself the quality of the code examples, the documentation, and the developer support.