# What Mac/iOS/Portable library can I use for formatting information to print onto label paper?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, macos

I'm looking for an open source (or cheap commercial) library that handles the difficulty of formatting information for standard label paper (say Avery 5160) for example.  I would like to use the library in a Mac and iPhone app.  I saw this similar question for a dedicated label printer, but I am looking for a Mac compatible library that will work with label paper loaded into any printer:
[What options are available to developers for printing to a dedicated label printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425617/what-options-are-available-to-developers-for-printing-to-a-dedicated-label-print)

Alternatively, I'm interested in suggestions about my best strategy for doing it myself... I'm not up for figuring out the intricacies of many different paper formats - I would probably target just one kind of US Letter label paper and one kind of A4 label paper.  Which are the most popular?

Comment: Have you thought about generating pdfs and then printing them?   Not sure if this helps, but its another direction to try.  http://www.html5marketplace.com/pdf/index.shtml

Comment: Yeah!  Now if only it allowed graphics on the labels, which it looks to me like it doesn't...  Still, the code might be a good starting point for translation into a C library.  I could also use it directly through a webview though I suppose...  Ah, but again no pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having written a (closed source) Mac codebase that actually does this, I can tell you that it's not the most difficult thing in the world. My codebase only supports Avery labels. I have a resource file in the app with geometry info for each kind of label (number of rows, columns, margin sizes, gutter sizes, etc.). I use this to layout a grids of properly sized subviews of the main print view, where each subview is one label. Each subview is responsible for modifying the layout of its information to fit its size. Conceivably this could be done using Cocoa Autolayout now (my code predates Autolayout).

You can download a CSV version of my label dimensions file [here](https://gist.github.com/armadsen/5084458).

EDIT: I might also mention that you'll need to do some significant extra work for a solution that works on both Mac and iOS. The printing APIs are quite different between the two platforms. Even if you use a custom view to do printing on iOS, UIView and NSView aren't exactly the same. Still, with some careful planning, you should be able to come up with something that at least shares common core code on both platforms.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the file, it will be very helpful to a lot of people reading this question I'm sure.  I'm still surprised there's no library though, so I'll keep the question open.

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed there was much demand for this. I don't expect that that many developers want to add label printing to their app. Perhaps when I have some time I'll clean up my code, make it nicely extensible, and release it publicly...